# How do I get the field 'subsidiary.federalidnumber' in an Advanced PDF/HTML Template printed from Item Fulfillment?

Tags: netsuite

In the template I have the following code;

```
<p>1-${record.subsidiary.federalIdNumber}</p>
<p>2-${record.subsidiary.custrecord_invoice_company_email}</p>
<p>3-${record.subsidiary.custrecord_invoice_company_phone}</p>
```

The last two lines return the expected values but the federalIdNumber gives the following error:
ERROR: Field 'subsidiary.federalIdNumber' Not Found
I have also tried all lower case (federalidnumber), same error.

I know the field exist, works on other SO prints. Any other ways to get this field?

Answer (score 0):

It's just `${subsidiary.federalidnumber}` No `record.` prefix. It is the transaction's subsidiary not the user's though.

weirdly I just took a look at some working templates. note the test vs getting the value:

```
<#if record.subsidiary.fedralidnumber?has_content>
    <b>GST Number: ${subsidiary.federalidnumber}</b>
</#if>
```